# Is there a way to calculate data faster in Python when dealing with large amounts of data?

Tags: python, database, performance, calculation

I am new to coding. Please help me fix my code. The code works fine and counts everything correctly. But the speed of its execution is very low. The final.csv file has 800,000 lines of data, and the code counts each line over a specific time period. Maybe there are some ways to get the maximum speed of code execution? For the first 50,000 lines, he counted 20 iterations per second, on the 75,000th line there are already 10 iterations, the further the line, the slower the code...

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

df = pd.read_csv('final.csv')
df['DATE_G'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_G'])
df = df.sort_values(by='DATE_G')
min_date = df['DATE_G'].min()

def calculate_365_days_totals(player_id, date, coverage=None):

    past_year_data = df[(df['DATE_G'] < date - pd.DateOffset(days=730)) & (df['DATE_G'] >= min_date)]
    if coverage:
        player_data1 = past_year_data[(past_year_data['ID1_G'] == player_id) & (past_year_data['ID_C_T'] == coverage)]
        player_data2 = past_year_data[(past_year_data['ID2_G'] == player_id) & (past_year_data['ID_C_T'] == coverage)]
    else:
        player_data1 = past_year_data[(past_year_data['ID1_G'] == player_id)]
        player_data2 = past_year_data[(past_year_data['ID2_G'] == player_id)]

    sum_win_sets = player_data1['ID1_WinSet'].sum() + player_data2['ID2_WinSet'].sum()
    sum_win_games = player_data1['ID1_Games_Win'].sum() + player_data2['ID2_Games_Win'].sum()
    sum_loose_sets = player_data2['ID1_WinSet'].sum() + player_data1['ID2_WinSet'].sum()
    sum_loose_games = player_data2['ID1_Games_Win'].sum() + player_data1['ID2_Games_Win'].sum()

    return sum_win_sets, sum_win_games, sum_loose_sets, sum_loose_games


with tqdm(total=len(df), desc='Calculating totals') as pbar:
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        df.at[i, 'ID1_365_WinSet'], df.at[i, 'ID1_365_WinGame'], df.at[i, 'ID1_365_LooseSet'], df.at[
            i, 'ID1_365_LooseGame'] = calculate_365_days_totals(row['ID1_G'], row['DATE_G'])

        df.at[i, 'ID2_365_WinSet'], df.at[i, 'ID2_365_WinGame'], df.at[i, 'ID2_365_LooseSet'], df.at[
            i, 'ID2_365_LooseGame'] = calculate_365_days_totals(row['ID2_G'], row['DATE_G'])

        coverage = row['ID_C_T']
        if coverage in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
            df.at[i, f'ID1_{coverage}_Win_Set_365'], df.at[i, f'ID1_{coverage}_Win_Game_365'], df.at[
                i, f'ID1_{coverage}_Loose_Set_365'], df.at[
                i, f'ID1_{coverage}_Loose_Game_365'] = calculate_365_days_totals(row['ID1_G'], row['DATE_G'], coverage)

            df.at[i, f'ID2_{coverage}_Win_Set_365'], df.at[i, f'ID2_{coverage}_Win_Game_365'], df.at[
                i, f'ID2_{coverage}_Loose_Set_365'], df.at[
                i, f'ID2_{coverage}_Loose_Game_365'] = calculate_365_days_totals(row['ID2_G'], row['DATE_G'], coverage)
        pbar.update(1)
df.to_csv('updated_final_period3.csv', index=False)
```

I need to calculate three time spans:

1. Code with this time span ran for ~20 hours

```
past_year_data = df[(df['DATE_G'] < date) & (df['DATE_G'] >= date - pd.DateOffset(days=365))]
```

2. Code with this time span ran for ~20 hours

```
past_year_data = df[(df['DATE_G'] < date - pd.DateOffset(days=365)) & (df['DATE_G'] >= date - pd.DateOffset(days=730))]
```

3. The code with this length of time I could not execute, because it takes an infinite amount of time :(

```
past_year_data = df[(df['DATE_G'] < date - pd.DateOffset(days=730)) & (df['DATE_G'] >= min_date)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are recalculating the past year's data for each row, which is unnecessary. because you have sorted the data by date, lets try to calculate the totals cumulatively for each date, then subtract the cumulative totals from 730 days ago.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.read_csv('final.csv')
df['DATE_G'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_G'])
df = df.sort_values(by='DATE_G')

cumulative_totals = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
totals_730_days_ago = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for col in ['WinSet', 'WinGame', 'LooseSet', 'LooseGame']:
    for prefix in ['ID1_365_', 'ID2_365_']:
        df[prefix + col] = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    cumulative_totals[row['ID1_G']]['WinSet'] += row['ID1_WinSet']
    cumulative_totals[row['ID1_G']]['WinGame'] += row['ID1_Games_Win']
    cumulative_totals[row['ID2_G']]['LooseSet'] += row['ID2_WinSet']
    cumulative_totals[row['ID2_G']]['LooseGame'] += row['ID2_Games_Win']

    df.at[i, 'ID1_365_WinSet'] = cumulative_totals[row['ID1_G']]['WinSet'] - totals_730_days_ago[row['ID1_G']]['WinSet']
    df.at[i, 'ID1_365_WinGame'] = cumulative_totals[row['ID1_G']]['WinGame'] - totals_730_days_ago[row['ID1_G']]['WinGame']
    df.at[i, 'ID1_365_LooseSet'] = cumulative_totals[row['ID2_G']]['LooseSet'] - totals_730_days_ago[row['ID2_G']]['LooseSet']
    df.at[i, 'ID1_365_LooseGame'] = cumulative_totals[row['ID2_G']]['LooseGame'] - totals_730_days_ago[row['ID2_G']]['LooseGame']

    if i > 0 and df.at[i-1, 'DATE_G'] < row['DATE_G'] - pd.DateOffset(days=730):
        totals_730_days_ago[row['ID1_G']]['WinSet'] = cumulative_totals[row['ID1_G']]['WinSet']
        totals_730_days_ago[row['ID1_G']]['WinGame'] = cumulative_totals[row['ID1_G']]['WinGame']
        totals_730_days_ago[row['ID2_G']]['LooseSet'] = cumulative_totals[row['ID2_G']]['LooseSet']
        totals_730_days_ago[row['ID2_G']]['LooseGame'] = cumulative_totals[row['ID2_G']]['LooseGame']

df.to_csv('updated_final_period3.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi, @Saxtheowl, thanks for trying to help! But your code is not correct.
Here is a photo of the result of your code calculations:
https://imgur.com/IMFZnPR
Here's what my code looks like:
https://imgur.com/uG8yWbh

Comment: Hello, no screenshoot please, upload your file somewhere or paste as text